# Android 3D Barchart

Tags: android, 3d, bar-chart

I am making an Application in which i need to implement 3D bar chart. I searched alot but not found any 3d barchart lib...

Here Is quick overview of problems I am facing to draw 3d bar chart.

Orson Charts - I found one library which can satisfy my need but it is paid (High rates). (http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/android/index.html)

Google chart library - which draws bar chart using API call which we don't want . Our application should work offline. (https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

jFreeChart - This is java library but uses swing packages to draw graphs. Swing is not included in android so there is limitation to use this library. (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartPieChart3DDemo2withRotation.htm)

aFreeChart - This is designed for android which used above (jFreeChart) library but they have not included 3D drawing facility for bar chart. (http://afreechart.googlecode.com/svn/doc/screenshot/index.html)

Please suggest me if there is any possibility of using any library..

Comment: `I searched alot but not found any 3d barchart lib...` Where did you search? on "The adventures of Mickey Mouse"? Try this page https://android-arsenal.com/tag/40

Comment: @Mehtab Ahmed did you find any answer??

Comment: @KJEjava48 yes I found solution. I used fusioncharts

Answer (score 1):

Try this libraries

```
1. https://github.com/jfree/orson-charts

2. https://github.com/blackfizz/EazeGraph

3. https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart
```

There are so many libraries in GitHub.

Comment: thnx brother for your reply but i am looking for 3D lib for free... orson-charts are paid...... EazeGraph and MPAndroidChart not support 3d charts these are 2D libs

Comment: Try with the first link, which I have given, its github link.

Comment: I downloaded the zip file from github but its not android project how i can use this in my android application .. please bro guide me little thnx